# How can I use subfiles and standalone for several generations of LaTeX files?

Tags: standalone, subfiles

I am writing my thesis in LaTeX, and my literature review now includes some TikZ figures.  I can compile the individual figures, and I can compile the whole thesis, but I can't compile the literature review itself.

I was able to build a minimum working example which demonstrates my issue.  This is my first time writing a MWE and also my first time using `filecontents` so please feel free to suggest how I might improve what I've done here.

```
% "pdflatex thesis.tex" works correctly
% "pdflatex varieties.tex" works correctly
% "pdflatex litreview.tex" does not work correctly, and generates the following output:
% ! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
% 
% See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
% Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
%  ...
% 
% l.5 \documentclass
%                   {standalone}
\begin{filecontents}{thesis.tex}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % just for the MWE
\usepackage{blindtext} % just for the MWE
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\input{preamble}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Lit Review}
    \subfile{litreview}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{preamble.tex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{litreview.tex}
\documentclass[thesis.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    \blindtext
    \begin{figure}
        \input{varieties}%
        \caption{Caption}
    \end{figure}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{varieties.tex}
\documentclass{standalone}
\ifstandalone
    \input{preamble}%
\fi
\begin{document}
    \tikz[mindmap,concept color=red,text=black,grow cyclic]
        \node[concept] {Traditional}; % [clockwise from=0]
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
```

I've asked around and searched this forum for answers but haven't found a solution that allows me to build all three documents correctly.  Please help!

**EDIT**: Please note that I have no hard-and-fast reason to use both `standalone` and `subfiles`.  I started with `subfiles` because the pattern worked for me, and `standalone` worked well for the figure.  I would love to see a MWE which does what my MWE does but with either `standalone` or `subfiles` but not both, if using both together isn't considered a best practice.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Any pointer for the particular `thesis` class you're using?

Comment: I haven't looked into these issues in a while, but the solution I have been using has worked for years and continues to work: Just use the `standalone` package (don't see why you also need `subfiles`) and _all_ files should use the same preamble. So, if there is a reason you need both, then please add that to the question.  One possible issue I see is that `varieties.tex` invokes `\input{preamble}` and `preamble.tex` invokes `\input{varieties}`!

Comment: @egreg the specific `thesis` class that I'm using is `beavtex` which I've got at https://github.com/mathuin/beavtex and which is based on the `book` class.  Oh, and thank you for the welcome!

Comment: @PeterGrill The `preamble.tex` file above only contains two lines, one to use TikZ and another to select a particular library.  The `varieties.tex` file imports the preamble only when compiled standalone, as the preamble would otherwise be imported already.  As for why I need both, I don't necessarily need both.  However, I'm new to multi-file LaTeX, and using both has gotten me close to my solution.  If you know a way to rewrite what I have posted above with only `standalone`, please post it and I'll mark it as the solution if it works for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of tinkering, I was able to rewrite my example using only `standalone` as per @PeterGrill's suggestion.

Here is my answer:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{thesis.tex}
\documentclass{book}
\input{preamble}
\begin{document}

    \chapter{Lit Review}
    \input{litreview}%

\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{preamble.tex}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % just for the MWE
\usepackage{blindtext} % just for the MWE
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{litreview.tex}
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\input{preamble}
\begin{document}

    \blindtext

    \begin{figure}
        \input{varieties}%
        \caption{Caption}
    \end{figure}

    \blindtext

\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{varieties.tex}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\input{preamble}
\begin{document}

    \tikz[mindmap,concept color=red,text=black,grow cyclic]
        \node[concept] {Traditional}; % [clockwise from=0]

\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Placeholder content.
\end{document}
```

This MWE has some other improvements:  the wrapper file now compiles without error and there is some additional whitespace which makes the output a little cleaner.

The key to this solution was the addition of `preview` and `tikz` as options to the `standalone` document class declaration.  These additions make the individual files compile correctly.  It's possible that the `tikz` option may not be necessary, but it also acts as a reminder to me that that's a picture file, so I'm keeping it.